# Leafletjs prevent dragging on specific area of marker

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

I'm using leafletjs for a non-geographic application where a user can add Icons (markers) to the map and draw lines between the 'ports' of different icons.
A port is simply defined as an x,y location relative to the top left corner of the icon viewport (icons are SVG).

I extended `L.Marker` to provide an `SVGMarker` class and implemented an `onMouseOver` function to detect when the mouse is over a port (within a tolerance) and change the cursor appropriately.

The markers are defined as `draggable` using leaflets' dragging capabilities.

Now I want to implement an `onMouseDown` function to start drawing a line when the user clicks on a port and starts dragging.

How can I override the dragging capabilities when my `onMouseDown` function detects I am near a port?

```
onMouseDown: function(event) {
  let nearPort = false;

  const { offsetX, offsetY } = event.originalEvent;
  const { ports } = this.options;
  for (let i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) {
    const currentPort = ports[i];

    // Calculate euclidian distance from mouse press location to the current port location
    const dist = distance(currentPort.x, offsetX, currentPort.y, offsetY);
    nearPort = (dist < this.options.tolerance);
    if (nearPort) {
       // TODO: Prevent marker from being dragged and start drawing line
       break;
    }
  }


}
```